# Look up VAT number

Tags: php, codeigniter

You can verify the validity of a VAT number of all member states by entering the number for which you wish to check the validity.
The information relating to the VAT identification data is recorded by the national authorities and stored in databases.

The information that can be requested concerns the validity of a VAT identification number, name, address, etc.

Is there a code to do this, I tried but I can't figure out how to find a script for it

Here is an example, `BTW-opzoeken.be`.

Comment: You need to find an API that will do that. A simple Google search turns up several.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this form validator

Read documentation and see example:

http://formvalidation.io/validators/vat/